# ¿Cómo alinear verticalmente inputs en un form?

Tags: css, bootstrap, formularios, bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="card-block">
  <div class="form-group row card-block">
    <label for="optradio" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Number of Guests</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option1" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option2" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option3" value="3">3</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option4" value="4">4</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option5" value="5">5</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option6" value="6">6</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row card-block">
    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Y se ve así:

[image: Align Problem]

Como se puede observar, los radio, los input y el button están desalineados. Todo esto está dentro de un card-body, aunque es irrelevante porque también sucede si no lo está.

Hay muchas soluciones acá, pero ninguna me funcionó. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Tienes que poner en dos Row distintos

Comment: ¿Eso no haría que los radio pasen abajo del label al igual que los input date y time? No veo cómo eso me puede ayudar.

Comment: Allí te muestro

Comment: Añade un estilo display: block; en cada input

Comment: Dices "_Hay muchas soluciones acá, pero ninguna me funcionó_", ¿podrías compartir algunas de las soluciones que probaste y no funcionaron? De ese modo no tendríamos que repetir cosas que ya probaste, o podríamos ver si había algún error al aplicarlos al código que se pueda solucionar.

Comment: Además, ¿cuáles son los estilos de `.card-block`? No parecen propios de Bootstrap 4. Deberías poner el código CSS propio relacionado al problema.

Comment: @SantiagoAlmeida no funcionó.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro no sé de dónde es, solo sé que lo encontré en Stackoverflow como resolución a un problema de márgenes de la card que tenía.

Comment: aquí un link a los diferentes tipos de form que tiene bootstrap4 -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/

y para ser más específicos ->
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#horizontal-form

Answer (score 1):

Respetando las rejillas, pones dos row, dentro de la columna de los input

```
<div class="form-group row card-block">
   <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
       <label for="lastname" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
     <div class="row">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eso sólo me alinea los dos inputs y encima me los deja lejísimo del label.

Comment: Tienes que aplicar lo mismo para tus check

Comment: Gracias, pero el espaciado no me terminaba de convencer, era demasiado y luego tendría que cambiar el padding.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 4 usa FlexBox para las columnas, y flexbox tiene la propiedad     [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) que te permite alinear los elementos dentro del contenedor flex de forma vertical (análogamente a como lo hace [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) de forma horizontal). Sólo tendrías que darle el valor `center`.

Parece que `.card-block` es lo que contiene a los diferentes inputs, entonces puedes poner `align-items: center;` para que se alineen verticalmente. Algo así:

```css
.card-block {
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form class="card-block">
  <div class="form-group row card-block">
    <label for="optradio" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Number of Guests</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option1" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option2" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option3" value="3">3</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option4" value="4">4</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option5" value="5">5</label>
    <label class="radio">
<input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option6" value="6">6</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row card-block">
    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Esa es una de las cosas que intenté y no funcionan. Pero ya lo solucioné. Con meter todos los radio en un div de col-12 funcionó. Gracias!

Comment: @FacundoYuffrida funcionar, funciona (se puede ver en el código ejecutable de arriba)... otra cosa es que no funcione con tu código porque haya algún conflicto o algo (por eso te pedía que añadieras más en los comentarios de la pregunta). Deberías compartir lo que conseguiste y te funcionó para que le pueda servir de ayuda a otros usuarios que puedan tener el mismo problema (lo menos que conseguirías sería un +1 por mi parte).

Comment: Correcto, muchas gracias por recordarme. Ahí lo comenté.

Answer (score 1):

Al final solucioné el problema poniendo todos los radios dentro de un `div` con clase `col-12`.

Me funcionó lo siguiente:

```
<form class="card-block">
    <div class="form-group row card-block">
        <label for="optradio" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Number of Guests</label>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option1" value="1">1</label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option2" value="2">2</label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option3" value="3">3</label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option4" value="4">4</label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option5" value="5">5</label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="radioOption" name="optradio" id="option6" value="6">6</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row card-block">
        <label for="lastname" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row card-block">
        <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Reserve</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```